# passenger-memory-stats - root privileges

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, phusion-passenger

When I run 'passenger-memory-stats' on my ubuntu server as root I get the following error :

```
-bash: passenger-memory-stats: command not found
```

If I run this command as a user ('deploy' in my case) I get the passenger results but I get the following warning:

```
*** WARNING: Please run this tool as root. Otherwise the private dirty RSS of processes cannot be determined.
```

So what I need to know is how can I get 'passenger-memory-stats' to run as root. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

*** ERROR MESSAGE ***

```
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2   p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find   passenger (>= 0) amongst [minitest-1.6.0, rake-0.8.7, rdoc-2.5.8] (Gem::LoadError)
from /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2- p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
from /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1208:in `gem'
from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/passenger-memory-stats:18:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I just re-installed ruby and passenger and now everything seems to be working fine. Not sure what I did last time?

Answer (score 1):

You can determine the full path of an executable file using the command:

```
$ which passenger-memory-stats
```

You need to make sure the root `PATH` includes the path to this executable to be able to execute it. Otherwise, you need to provide the full path to the executable when you want to execute it such as:

```
$ sudo /path/to/passenger-memory-stats
```

Comment: When I do 'which passenger-memory-stats' nothing is shown. Am I missing something for 'which' to work?

Comment: If you have done this as root, this explain why you can not execute it. If so, try it again as normal user and search for the returned path in root `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: this is what I get from a normal user: which passenger-memory-stats
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/passenger-memory-stats . If I do 'sudo /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/passenger-memory-stats' it will error. I've updated my original post with the error message. Seems odd it can't find passenger when I know its installed :S